# Bind a Super key to Alt_R in i3

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, i3-wm, shortcut-keys

I'm setting up i3 for the first time and I ran into a problem. For my modkey I can choose between Mod1(Alt keys) and Mod4(Super key). I need my Left Alt key free for my text editor, so I can't choose Mod1 (alt keys), but Mod4 (Super) is difficult to press and my hand started cramping after a few minutes. I want to set my Right alt key as my i3 modkey, but it's not possible since Mod1 refers to both Left Alt and Right Alt. Can I somehow rebind Right Alt to mimic the Super key? Or alternatively, can I somehow have Mod1 include only Right Alt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dconf write "/org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options" "['altwin:swap_ralt_rwin']"
```

or

```
setxkbmap -option altwin:swap_ralt_rwin
```

This should swap the ALT_R and WIN_R key. You may find this feature in 'Gnome-Tweak' `sudo apt install gnome-tweak`

---

Sometimes the ALT_R key behavior is somewhat difficult and the commands above don't do what you or me expect.
It is simple and quick to change the keycode for ALT-R. (And this is not a correct solution, my guess.)

`vi /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev`

```
<RALT> = 134;
<RWIN> = 108;
```

Comment: As you said the commands only kind of help. `setxkbmap -option altwin:swap_alt_win ` makes Left Super become Alt, Left Alt become Left Super, Right Alt become Right Super. I only want the Right Alt to become Right Super. Changing keycodes seems to work the best.

Comment: Soory my typo correction `setxkbmap -option altwin:swap_ralt_rwin`